# How can i run Ui tests without viewing the screen in Windows?

Tags: azure, coded-ui-tests

I have an app service in Azure that I want to run some UI tests on . The issue is that I need to always have the VM screen visible for the tests to run.
Is there a way I can run them in command line or something that Azure can offer ?

Comment: Is this a Web app or a Windows desktop app?

Comment: It is a web app in Azure

Comment: Maybe you could use a headless browser? As long as you can run the Web app somewhere.

Comment: When i launch a new browser i use the following;    manager.LaunchNewBrowser(manager.Settings.Web.DefaultBrowser, true); and manager is ArtOfTest.WebAii.Core. Can i set headless as an option here ?